# How to display a Table for IEnumerable property on a Microsoft Report

Tags: c#, vb.net, report, reportviewer

I've got a class with the following properties which I'd like to display on a Microsoft Report:

Class: Sales

```
Property    Type
DateOfSale  DateTime
TellerName  String
Purchase    List(Of Purchases)
```

The definition of the Purchases class is as follows:
Class: Purchases

```
Property    Type
Item        String
Quantity    Integer
UnitCost    Decimal
TotalCost   Decimal
```

My objective is to create a report showing each transaction (`Sales`) that was made within a particular time span [say, within one week].

I've so far been able to display the `DateOfSale` and `TellerName` on the report using TextBoxes.
I'd like to display the `Purchase` for each sale as a Table and that is where I'm stumped.

Does anyone know how I can display the `Purchase` property as a table on the report and sum the `TotalCost` of all the purchases made in a given `Sales` at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way around it.
Just create a class which holds all the necessary properties and create as many instances as necessary.
Passing them as arguments to the DataSource of the report displays them all there.